# How to Stop ads on splash activity

Tags: android

I have a problem when I test app on my mobile phone ads come on splash activity which one I not want to show ads on splash activity I want when I open app show splash activity with my logo and after delayMillis: 2500 then its go on main activity and show ads.

so come to the point how I can disable ads on splash activity?

**Here is my splash activity codes.**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },2500);

    }
}
```

Comment: how ads are displaying in this activity as there is no code of ads

Comment: I know but bro when I open app on phone then first show Interstitial add then we need to close add after the closing ad its go on main activity

Comment: Have you added any ads related code in your xml?

Comment: Al-Amin Bro in Activity-Splash.xml i no add any ads code just i add logo "android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView" but i add ads code in main-Activity.xml but when i open app Interstitial ads come on Splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code their is no chance of showing ad from your own app. This could happened from a third party software in your phone.

You could share the codes of MainActivity then we could find out if there is any problem.

If there is no problem with your main activity, then I suggest you to use a Ad blocker tool in your phone to find out that app who is showing that kinda ad.
Best of Luck.

**Edit**

You have used ad in your main activity. Removing that ad from main activity will solve your problem. Use this code instead.

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private WebView myWebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.onlineurdututor.com/");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

I just remove every interstitial ad related code from your app. I just keep the banner ad. Use this code. Now the problem should be solved. Enjoy.

Comment: I didn't see your MainActivity Code

Comment: Please check this link https://gist.github.com/PakSofts/f02d4d0c5c3971bd075fd484d2d36505

Comment: SplashActivity Codes Here: https://gist.github.com/PakSofts/d1b34bff5c365412fccd0a18f241330a

Comment: MainActivity.XML CODES HERE: https://gist.github.com/PakSofts/a875130d8380cbd5049a2bf80f32e773

Comment: Your solution added in the answer. Check it.

Comment: SplashActivity.xml codes here: https://gist.github.com/PakSofts/b3e0f21ecf0a95d1fd7055948405bfc3

Comment: Bro, i add this ads code in MainActivity because i want to show my google it's on my app but i just want its ads to come on MainActivity not come on SplashActivity screen.

Comment: Okay. You know the rules of Interstitial ad? those ad comes between two activities/pages. [Check This](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201350?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) .When The splash screen activity finished and main activity starts that is the exact time for load the ad. that's why it shows before main activity. I think you got cleared.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
           
showAdIfAvailable();
          
}
```

with this

```
 @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
public void onStart() {
            if (!(currentActivity instanceof SplashActivity)) {
                showAdIfAvailable();
            }
}
```